# How to change price on product filter result page?

Tags: magento2, product-list, catalogsearch

I've created a custom module to show the installments price, and it is working OK in the product page and category page, for this, I've created a plugin, my **di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

To show the installments on category page, and a layout **catalog_product_view.xml** to show on product view page.

But in filter result page (catalogsearch_result_index) it does not work, I've tryed to set my plugin, to my custom price render as I've done with category page, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

And I've tryed to set a layout file **catalogsearch_result_index.xml**, like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="search.result">
                <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <!--My Custom Block-->
                    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Parcelamento" after="product.info.price"
                        name="product.info.price.installment.block"
                        template="Vendor_Module::list.phtml">
                    </block>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But nothing works, how can I override the price render for catalogsearch results? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the situation is that `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct` is a virtual type, with is seted in `Magento\CatalogSearch\etc\frontend\di.xml`

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

So, it points to `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`. I just set a new `preference` in my custom module, like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

With that, category listing and search results use now my custom price method. I hope it helps someone.